# How to count the number of rows of a dictionary within a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a project where I need to find out the number of rows of purchase orders in our system.  Thus allowing me to edit the POs by appending another row to the order.

The way the data is stored is as follows:

```
id  rows
0   49696   [{'productID': 57174, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNam...
1   49691   [{'productID': 4036, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemName...
2   49690   [{'productID': 4036, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemName...
3   54827   [{'productID': 155099, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
4   54826   [{'productID': 155099, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
5   54825   [{'productID': 155099, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
6   54824   [{'productID': 155099, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
7   54823   [{'productID': 155098, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
8   54822   [{'productID': 155098, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
9   54821   [{'productID': 155098, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
10  54820   [{'productID': 155098, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
11  53580   [{'productID': 153856, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
12  53576   [{'productID': 153856, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
13  53572   [{'productID': 153856, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
14  53567   [{'productID': 153856, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
15  53560   [{'productID': 153273, 'serviceID': 0, 'itemNa...
```

What I want to be able to do is to query each row and find out the number of rows of each dictionary there is, hence number of rows per PO and append that as a new series to my DataFrame (nrRows).

I can't figure out the bet way to query the dictionary of rows on each row within my DataFrame...  I know how to unpack them into a DataFrame each but I can't figure the most efficient way to return just the number of rows and append it to my original DF.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Your list of dict is a part your column `rows`? i.e. strings?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand the issue, but could you be looking for something like:

```
my_df["rows"].apply(lambda r: len(r))
```

"Number of rows of a dictionary" is the part that is confusing. How do you define rows here?